# forming html table/block , the style issue for beginner

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, datatable, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just learn code about 2 weeks, I mostly study myself , and learn fro web and chatgpt, now I get the problem I couldn't solve myself

**I'm building 3x2 table/block , that shows the status count I want, I get the problem with showing, I really want it to be prettier**

The key word I search on google is :bootstrap table and columns
(maybe from here my keyword is wrong)

- the table I expect [(table I want)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IEi0.png)
- the table I made [(pic2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWUcX.png)

Problem: no margin no space for each column, and I want showing 6 block with 6 different color, not same row same color

This is the code I tried

```
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <th scope="col">Sl No.</th>
        <th scope="col">Class</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="table-active">
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>11111</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-default">
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>22222</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-primary">
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>3333</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

---

- tried code 02
  [(pic)  tried code 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rsjz.png)

the layout wanna be same as the table I expect [(table I want)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IEi0.png) there still get tiny part need to adjust, *but I get no idea*, pls give me a hand

```
      
<style>
  .table {
    border-spacing: 50px;
    width: auto;
    border-collapse: separate;
  
  }

  .table td {
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 70px;
  }

  .table-active td {
    background-color: #FFC0CB;
  }

  .table-default td {
    background-color: #ECECEC;
  }

  .table-primary td {
    background-color: #ADD8E6;
  }

  .table-secondary td {
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
  }

  .table-success td {
    background-color: #90EE90;
  }

  .table-danger td {
    background-color: #FF6347;
  }
</style>

<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="table-active">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>table-active</td>
      <td>table-active</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-default">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>table-default</td>
      <td >table-active</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I would state that this is not a table as it is not tabular data in this configuration but a CSS-Grid.